# Is there hierarchical taxonomy support in Umbraco 8?

Tags: taxonomy, hierarchical, umbraco8

we are considering to use Umbraco 8 as CMS system for displaying a number of items.
Those items must be tagged with tags from multiple hierarchies.

For example:

ITEM: horse, tags: livingbeing/animal/mammal, word/english/noun

Is this possible with Umbraco 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box, I'd say. Umbraco has a Tags datatype within which I guess you could *name* the tags whatever you want, including / and whatever. But they would still just be a simple list of tags.

Also, the built in Tags datatype allows editors to create whatever new tags they want, there isn't an option to restrict editors to choose from a defined set of tags.

One common solution to this is to create simple content nodes (in a hierarchy if you want) and use them as "tags" instead. Then you can fairly easily create a tag picker with which you are only allowed to select existing nodes/tags.